# Link to arbitrary part of text?

Tags: hyperref, links

I have a long text and I want to create a link within the document to a particular paragraph (for example write something like "as shown here" where clicking on "here" will take the reader to that paragraph).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` pair:

Place the target (i.e. the place to be jumped to) with `\hypertarget{foo}{Your text}` and refer to it with `\hyperlink{foo}{Some other text}`.

The destination label `foo` must be unique of course.

If the link appears in `\section{...}` etc. arguments, care have to be taken. `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` have to be  protected then with `\protect` and to comfort `hyperref`, put it into a `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}` command then!

**Edit**

If the position to be linked to is near a counter being increased with `\refstepcounter`, a usual `\label{foo}` and `\ref{foo}` is easier of course!

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{With a hyperlink: \texorpdfstring{\protect\hyperlink{mylink}{As shown here}}{}}
\hyperlink{mylink}{As shown here}

\blindtext[5]

\hypertarget{mylink}{\textbf{Here is the anchor}}


\end{document}
```

[image]