# Cross referencing to forward parts

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm trying to make cross referencing to a forward part in my document using `\hyperref[<to_label>]{<link_text>}` but it seems because of `\label{}` is ahead of `\hyperref`, that's not defined when code is compiled, so the link does not work properly.

I'm using this code to include `enumerate` environment items in equations numbering

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}
\usepackage{chngcntr,etoolbox}
\newif\ifinenumerate
    \AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\inenumeratetrue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \theenumi\fi
  \arabic{equation}}

\renewcommand\thefigure{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \theenumi\fi
  \roman{figure}}
\makeatother
```

And this is my `hyperref` setup

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={...},
    pdfauthor={...},
    pdfsubject={...},
    pdfkeywords={...},
}
```

Here is a working example; as you can check my cross reference carries to last equation referenced instead of `\label` what I've defined.

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={...},
    pdfauthor={...},
    pdfsubject={...},
    pdfkeywords={...},
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifinenumerate
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\inenumeratetrue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \theenumi\fi
  \arabic{equation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test 1}
\subsection{test 1.1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item item a
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1         
        \begin{equation}
        a = b
        \end{equation}              
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1 subcase 1       
        \begin{equation}
        a = b
        \end{equation}
        I need to reference \hyperref[not:Note1]{forward}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
In here, for example \label{not:Note1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: all latex and hyperref cross referencing allows forward and backward references. please show a complete (small) document that fails  otherwise impossible to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Please provide compilable LaTeX code that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. Please be sure to state which document class you and with which options `hyperref` is loaded.

Comment: a forward reference will not resolve with the first run.  however, the value of the label will be placed in the `.aux` file, which is read in on subsequent runs, so after that is available, the reference should appear.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton here is the .aux of this MWE http://pastebin.com/p9X22365

Comment: there isn't anything to link to where you have the `\label{not:Note1}`.  you need to establish a proper target.  does this answer help: [Link to arbitrary part of text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280464/579)?

Comment: Is this question still 'alive' or shall we vote to close it as 'unclear'?

Comment: It is clear with @barbarabeeton answer, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a better strategy, for something that doesn't have an obvious "anchor" (like a
section heading or equation number) is to use a `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`
pair.  this is explained with a nice example in an answer to this question:
[Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462)

(trivial answer provided for question closed as duplicate.)