# Is there a way to put a label/tag in a (whole) list (either enumeration or itemization)

Tags: lists, itemize, labels

I would like to create an itemization (only text no math) and put a label on it so I can reference it late. I want to reference the whole list, not just a specific item in it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is possible to add numbering and labels to lists, but how should it look like? Do you have a specific layout in mind?

Comment: I am not sure how I can describe my question even better. To make an attempt, I would like it to look similar to how an equation with split looks like. However, instead of many lines of math, it will have text seperated in items.

Comment: The itemization block is just ordinary text.  You can establish it as an anchor, label it, and refer to that later.  See [Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462)

Comment: but equations have a number, do you want to number all lists in the document (whcih would be possible if unusual) normally the list is in some subsection and you can reference  "the list in section \ref{...}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton, but this alone will not give a number to this text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes this is what I want to do. I know it is not common, otherwise I guess I would have found something already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems rather odd, but I think you are asking for

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{lst}
\newenvironment{lst}{%
\refstepcounter{lst}%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}}{%
\end{minipage}%
\makebox[.1\textwidth][r]{(\thelst)}%
\end{center}}

\begin{document}

zzzzz
\begin{lst}
 \label{aaa}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item zzz
 \item bbb
 \item 333
 \end{itemize}
\end{lst}


zzzzz
\begin{lst}
 \label{bbb}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item zzz
 \item bbb
 \item 333
 \end{itemize}
\end{lst}


See list \ref{bbb}, which is quite similar to list \ref{aaa}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. I do not understand why people find this weird :-). I just want to make lists with arguments/assumptions and compare them.