# Labeling and Referencing an arbitrary formula or text that is not necessarily inside cases, equation or align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I want to be able to label and reference a particular text in my LaTeX document without necessarily making it appear inside an `equation`, `align`, or `cases` environment. How can I do this?

For example is it possible to have something like this?

```
"This is a simple text that also contains $an \quad inline \quad formula$ inside itself!"    (♣)


As we discussed in (♣), everything could be labeled and referenced later on in $\latex$!
```

If label could not do this, how can I do such thing so that I can have the same functionality outside those environments and avoid doing it manually by typing `(♣)` by hand every time?

Comment: So, basically, you're saying that some object to be cross-referenced doesn't come with a "hook" of any known kind or type (or "stuff", as you put it), not even a hook provided by the `hyperref` package. Yet, somehow, LaTeX is supposed to provide a mechanism for latching on to an object that offers no hooks. Why the "I don't want to use hyperlinks and other stuff" stance? Incidentally, what might this "other stuff" be that you're ruling out *ex ante*? Unless we know exactly what you're ruling out, it's not really possible to figure out what may, in your view, be permissible.

Comment: Maybe the "other stuff" part is ambiguous. I meant by it the align and equation environments.

Comment: LaTeX's basic `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism rests the premise that `\label` can "latch on" to a counter variable -- specifically, the counter variable most recently incremented by a `\refstepcounter` instruction. For instance, the `\section{...}` instruction increments a counter called `section`, and an `equation` environment increments a counter called, you guessed it, `equation`. Any `\label` instructions that follow `\section` or `\begin{equation}` will be associated with the current value of the appropriate counter.

Comment: Let's for example say, can we generate the same example above without using equation/align environments and by avoiding the text to be a link? Maybe hypertext can do that. I thought it always makes your text a hyperlink.

Comment: Ah, I see. So can I define my own counters as well? Also, is it possible to use labels that use symbols like ♠, * (etc.) for a text and reference it later? How should I do that?

Comment: Please see [Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462/5001) for information on using `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108878/discussion-between-master-aka-and-mico).

Comment: About defining and using your own counters: I was under the impression that your premise was that the objects you wanted to cross-reference were *not* associated with counters such as `equation`; however, my impression may have been quite wrong. Sure, you could set up your own counter variables and increment them via `\refstepcounter`; I can guarantee, though, that your readers will have no idea what's going on when they start to see cross-references of the form `<someobject 15>` and cannot find any instances of `<someobject>`, let alone one that's numbered 15.