# How to \label + \ref arbitrary lines of text?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

We are currently working on a document which contains lists of things that are identified by 'semi-numbered' identifiers in a way that is easy for humans to understand but difficult to 1:1 automate using a new counter.

<sub>(To be precise, we're tasked with numbering our 'functional and nonfunctional requirements' according to the naming scheme indicated by the professor of a university course in software architecture. Some examples are `HL-1`, `FR-1.2`, `NFR-2.4b`)</sub>

Nonetheless We'd like to refer to these from throughout the document, as their identifier and ordering might change.

This is the reason why we are looking for a general way to define a label on a small piece of text that we can refer to (using `\ref`, `\nameref` or `\autoref`) which should then print the name we specified rather than e.g. the name of the section it was written in.

How could this be done?

---

There is some overlap between this question and [Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280462/link-to-arbitrary-part-of-text). However, whereas the solution posted there works well when the *reference* is free in deciding what to name the links, in our case we'd want to use whatever name is configured at the *label* to be used for all the references to it.

Comment: This will partly depend on how you're creating the small piece of text.  Are you labeling a theorem like environment?  Or a line of code?  Or your own thing that you've created with `newenvironment`?  Or `newcommand`?  Could you give us a short example?

Comment: @Teepeemm Interesting, I had not considered that. They are usually (at least currently) introduced as lines in a tabularx environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a basic implementation that sets problems using the `description` environment while you can set a specific "named `\label`" to these items that are correctly hyperlinked.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\namelabel}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}% Update the label text/name
  \label{#1}% Set the label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a list:
\begin{description}
  \item[HL-1] \namelabel{HL-1}
  This is a strange problem.
  
  \item[FR-1.2] \namelabel{FR-1.2}
  This is a weird problem.
  
  \item[NFR-2.4b] \namelabel{NFR-2.4b}
  This is a complicated problem.
\end{description}

See the weird problem called \ref{FR-1.2}.

\end{document}
```