# Insert a reference un a figure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm working on a book, and I want to add at the end of an exercise list an icon that if I click it then I go to the place of a specific reference. For example, usually, I write \ref{solutions} but in this way appears "Section 2", I want to click on an icon and goes to \ref{solutions}, only can be visible the icon, don't show 'section 2'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please show us an example document, with labels and references to them as you like to have. Form your description can be concluded, that your labels are wrongly inserted in your document.

Comment: Does the posting [Link to arbitrary part of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462/5001) help?